# ERROR: Wheel 'torch' located at C:\Users\ElectroMall\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-o34evj4q\torch-1.13.0+cu116-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is invalid

Tags: pytorch

i'm trying to intsall pytorch, but keep getting the error message "ERROR: Wheel 'torch' located at C:\Users\ElectroMall\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-o34evj4q\torch-1.13.0+cu116-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is invalid." while the download reaches 1.5 gig.

My CUDA version is 11.6.

I have Windows 11 pro and CUDA 11.6 toolkit + Python 3.9.8 64 bit installed.

Any idea why this keeps happening and how to fix this issue??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PT77.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I was getting a similar error message. 
Went to https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html 
Located the version from the error message and downloaded it.
Then run it in powershell and was able to complete the installation.